# sublimeJEDI syntax completion not working in sublime text 3 for tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, sublimetext3

Sublime text 3 Build 3126

Tensorflow auto-completions not working using sublimeJEDI.

Though they work for numpy.

Comment: Try using [Anaconda](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda) instead.